# take a picture of current image from webcam in Flash AS3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, webcam

So I've managed to view my webcam in a AS3 app with this code:

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class WebCam extends Sprite
    {   
        private var camara:Camera;
        private var video:Video;

        public function WebCam():void {
            setupCamera();
        }

        private function setupCamera():void
        {
            video = new Video(640, 480);
            camara = Camera.getCamera();
            camara.setMode(640, 480, 30);
            video.attachCamera(camara);
            addChild(video);
        }

    }

}
```

But I'm wondering if there is anyway to take a picture of the current image from the webcam and save it somewhere locally?

EDIT:

@Sean Here is my current code:

```
var camara;
var video;


//Get the camera reference.
camara = Camera.getCamera();


//Create a video instance
video = new Video(640, 480);


video.attachCamera(camara);

addChild(video);

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640, 480);
bitmapData.draw(video);

var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);

navnavClick.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(){
var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray);
});
```

That all works well, but the output image is just a blank (white) image. I've included the JPGEncoder class too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to draw the image to a `BitmapData`.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640, 480);
bitmapData.draw(video);
```

Then, you need to encode the `BitmapData`.  I would recommend an encoder that uses Alchemy, but Adobe is removing that from Flash Player.  So, you should use the slower [as3corelib JPGEncoder](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/images/JPGEncoder.as).

```
var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bitmapData);
```

You now have the raw bytes of the image file, and can write them to disk.

```
var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray);
```

(This part has to be called from a user-initiated action, like a click).

Comment: That looks pretty awesome Sean. You say `This part has to be called from a user-initiated action`, which part? The `var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray);` part?

Comment: Right, it's a security feature.  Flash won't let you open the "Save As..." dialog without the user clicking or pressing a key.

Comment: Hate to keep bugging you, but it seems to be saving a blank jpeg file. The file size seems right, but there is no image, just a blank white image...I'll edit my question with the current code. Thanks xD

Comment: ah, I see what I've done wrong. I should be drawing the image and encoding, on user click, not before. My bad. Thanks.

Comment: @navnav Drawing doesn't have to be in the click event, it just has to be done when the video is ready, which takes a couple seconds.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this code, I use it and it works fine:

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,30);
var video_es = new Video(cam.width, cam.height);
video_es.attachCamera(cam); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, snapIt); 
var screenS:BitmapData = new BitmapData(cam.width, cam.height); 
addChild(video_es);

function snapIt(e:MouseEvent):void { 
   screenS.draw(video_es) ;

   var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
   var byteArray:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(screenS);

   var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference();
   fileReference.save(byteArray, "test1.jpg");

}
```

Hope that helps